# Check if an element has a specific value, then modify another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a simple basic filter as `<ul class="list">` where all `<li class="item">` elements are hidden by default. Next to my filter are boxes, each with a list of items. They are fetched from the database like this:

```
<p class="item-list">Apples, Oranges, Bananas</p>
```

I've spent some time today trying to figure out a solution but I can't get it to work. This is what I had:

```
if ( $("p.item-list").is(":contains('Apples')")) {
    $(".list li.item:nth-child(1)").show();
} else if ( $("p.item-list").is(":contains('Oranges')")){
    $(".list li.item:nth-child(2)").show();
} else if ( $("p.item-list").is(":contains('Bananas')")){
    $(".list li.item:nth-child(3)").show();
} else if ( $("p.item-list").is(":contains('Berries')")){
    $(".list li.item:nth-child(4)").show();
}
```

I figured when the first "if" matches it stops so my approach was wrong. I can't think of a solution - well actually I can but my coding skills are limited :(

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: What is the desired result? That all `if`s are executed independently? Then simply don’t use `else`.

Comment: "I've spent some time today trying to figure out a solution" -- a solution to what?  Are we supposed to extrapolate from the post title: "Check if an element has a specific value, then modify another element"?  -- Even *it* is vague: modify *another* element?  Which other element?  Sorry if this seems nit-picky, but precision is going to help you improve your coding skills which you yourself admit are limited

Comment: Xufox, I feel so dumb right now. I can't even believe I didn't think of that. That fixed my problem *hides in shame*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to show `li` elements that correspond to a series of words. I'll assume your code is malformed, and you want to show all matches instead of just the first.

To do this, you can simplify by creating a list of words that correspond to each `li` to be potentially shown. Then in a loop (or `.forEach()`), if the current word is found in the text, you display the `li` for that word's index.

This is a solution without jQuery.

```js
var text = document.querySelector("p.item-list").textContent;
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".list li.item");
var search_words = [
  "Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Berries"
];

search_words.forEach((word, i) => {
  if (text.includes(word)) {
    items[i].classList.add("show");
  }
});
```

```css
.list li.item {
  display: none;
}

.list li.item.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="item-list">Apples, Oranges, Bananas</p>

<ul class="list">
  <li class=item>APPLES
  <li class=item>ORANGES
  <li class=item>BANANAS
  <li class=item>BERRIES
</ul>
```

Comment: That's amazing, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve. While I was able to fix the issue with my code by just removing the else part, your solution looks way better than mine! Thank you :)